# How to make a spectral response scatter plot in R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot the band value (B2, B3, B4, B8) for each for 7 land classes. I am trying to get a visual of the spectral signature of each class and how they differ from one another. I want to reproduce something like this:

[image]

Example data is here:

[image]

I researched approaches on how to do this but I can't seem to figure it out. I am very new to R.

Comment: Hi Erioderma, instead of a table you should present your sample data to potential helpers using `dput` function on your data, e.g. `dput(head(data))` and post the result in your question. That makes it easier to reproduce your code and you might get help faster.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to plot the mean value for each class, in Base R you can try this approach using `split` and `colMeans`:

simple, without cosmetics:

```
#create sample data
data=data.frame(B2=rnorm(14,5,0.4),B3=rnorm(14,5,0.6),B4=rnorm(14,5,0.2),B8=rnorm(14,5,0.4),Class_2=rep(paste0("C",1:7),each=2))

dataL <- split(data,data$Class_2)

#create empty plot    
plot(1,xlim=c(1,4),ylim=c(4,6),type="n")

#add points
for(i in 1:length(dataL)){
  points(1:4,colMeans(dataL[[i]][,1:4]),pch=19,col=rainbow(7)[i])
}
```

[image]

Same plot with some cosmetics:

```
par(mar=c(5,4,4,5))
plot(1,xlim=c(0.5,4.5),ylim=c(4,6),type="n",xlab="Band",ylab="Band mean",las=1,xaxt="n")
for(i in seq(4,6,0.25)) abline(h=i,col="grey")
for(i in 1:length(dataL)){
    points(1:4,colMeans(dataL[[i]][,1:4]),pch=19,col=rainbow(7)[i])
}
axis(1,at=1:4,colnames(data[,1:4]))
legend(4.8,5.5,pch=19,col=rainbow(7),names(dataL),bty="n",xpd=T)
```

[image]